# How to calculate percentage for each month by process

Tags: sql, percentage

I have table as below

```
Process status     startdate
A        complete  09/12/2020 01:12:00
A        complete  09/12/2020 02:13:00
A        failed    09/12/2020 13:15:00
B        complete  09/12/2020 01:00:00
A        complete  10/15/2020 01:00:00
B        complete  10/16/2020 01:12:00
B        failed    10/16/2020 15:00:00
```

Now I need to write sql to get complete percentage each month by each process. Below is expected result.

```
Process  MonthYear percentage
A        09/2020    33.33
A        10/2020    100
B        09/2020    100
B        10/2020    50
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: please tag your dbms

Answer (score 0):

extracting month/year depends on your database , but here is how you can do it in mysql:

```
select Process 
      , extract(month_year from startdate)
      , count(case when status ='completed' then 1 end)*1.00 / count(*) percentage
from tablename
group by Process , extract(month_year from startdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg()` to calculate the percentage.  I don't know what database you are using but date/time functions are highly database dependent.  A typical method would be:

```
select year(startdate), month(startdate), process,
       avg(case when status = 'completed' then 100.0 else 0 end)
from t
group by year(startdate), month(startdate), process;
```

You may need to adapt the year/date extraction to the database you are using.